# Changing content while a journey is active

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

If a journey is active, and I change the name of the data extension, email, move an email  or rename the journey, will it impact the running journey?

Answer (score 2):

- Do not change the name of the Entry source data extension or target DEs of Update Contact Events, this will lead to problems.
- You can move the Emails or data extensions, unless you change context (to/from shared to non-shared). References use only their name or ids.

The only time folders become relevant is a) when sharing is involved (see above) or b) when custom SSJS scripts use them for e.g. filtering.

- you can make changes on Emails even within a running Journey version, just do this directly from within Journey Builder. Just make sure to save the mail and follow the instructions "don't close this window" when saving :) during this message, the system takes care of the underlying Triggered Send Logics of stopping, changing, publishing and restarting.
- renaming the journey can only be done by creating a new version. So you can do nothing wrong inside a running version here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, so just to recap, never change the name of a DE of a running journey,
but can I rename emails?

Comment: Yes, you can make changes on Emails even within a running Journey version,  just do this directly from Journey Builder. Just make sure to save the mail and follow the instructions "don't close this window" when saving ;). I'll edit this into my answer.

Comment: I checked the journey and it appears I cant edit any emails when I double click on them?  I can click the entry source but not email

Comment: In a running journey, single-click on the Email so you see the statistics ("Email Analytics") ribbon on the left. This seems to run a bit finicky at times, but it does work, just confirmed again. In the ribbon, switch to "Activity Summary" and you see the email and can edit it.

Comment: ^cool thanks alot didnt see that, so I CAN edit an email's content including it's name but its recommended not to?

Comment: Yes you can. SUch changes don't exactly document themselves well, so I guess I'd only use it for urgent hotfixes or similar. I've seen usecases where the journey flow was ready months ahead of the email creative, and placeholder emails were replaced later down the road. So there are some valid scenarios - just don't go in blindly replacing your stuff if you can use versioning etc.

Answer (score 2):

The only time there would be a breaking 'effect' when changing a name/customerkey will have is if you are using AMPscript or SSJS to reference these (or some API calls).

Internally, SFMC utilizes the ObjectID of each of these resources, meaning that path and name are not really relevant to how they are referenced. There may be some unexpected behaviors, but it should still function.

That being said though, I would NEVER recommend making changes to any automation (or in this case, Journey) while it is still running. ANY change should be made while it is in a paused state and you should QA and test all changes prior to pushing back to live.

To do otherwise is to add a significant element of risk. This risk is not just of it breaking, but potentially catastrophic activities such as sending incorrect information to people en masse or otherwise corrupting your messaging to your customers. I can think of no viable argument to not require a blackout window to make the changes.